# Deserialising a JSON response with GSON, using Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I am attempting to parse the following JSON response with GSON:

```
{
  "total": 15,
  "page": 2,
  "pagesize": 10,
  "rep_changes": [
    {
      "user_id": 2341,
      "post_id": 2952530,
      "post_type": "question",
      "title": "unprotected access to member in property get",
      "positive_rep": 5,
      "negative_rep": 0,
      "on_date": 1275419872
    },
   {
      "user_id": 2341,
      "post_id": 562948,
      "post_type": "question",
      "title": "Do you have any recommendations on Blend/XAML books/tutorials for designers?",
      "positive_rep": 20,
      "negative_rep": 0,
      "on_date": 1270760339
    }
  ....
}
```

These are the two classes I have defined (each class contains the respective getters and setters):

```
public class Reputation {
    private int total;
    private int page;
    private int pagesize;
    private List<RepChanges> rep_changes;

public class RepChanges {
    private int user_id;
    private int post_id;
    private String post_type;
    private String title;
    private int positive_rep;
    private int negative_rep;
    private long on_date;
```

I have been unable to parse the RepChanges class into the rep_changes attribute in the Reputation class. Any thoughts?

Note: I have managed to parse total, page, and pagesize (these are non-complex attributes). This is what I have done:

To parse the total, page, and pagesize, I used (and worked fine):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reputation rep = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Reputation.class);

//doing this works:
int page = rep.getPage();
System.out.println(page);
```

However, when doing:

```
List<RepChanges> rep_changes = rep.getRep_changes();
for(RepChanges r : rep_changes){
    System.out.println(r.toString());
}
```

I (technically) do not get an error, but the following (which seems like a memory location):

```
stackoverflow.objects.RepChanges@116bb691
```

Comment: What's the problem when you try to deserialize it?

Comment: @colinD, I edited the problem, I explained a bit further...hope that gives better insight ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Repchanges` class, configure your own `toString()` method similar to this:

```
public String toString ()
{
    return "RepChanges [user_id=" + user_id + 
            ", post_id=" + post_id + 
            ", post_type=" + post_type + 
            ", title=" + title + 
            ", positive_rep=" + positive_rep + 
            ", negative_rep=" + negative_rep + 
            ", on_date=" + on_date + "]";
}
```

Comment: and instead of the foreach loop, simply call the this method, I guess right? But how can I be sure that the elements from the JSON response is actually stored within the attribute I want it stored in?
Thanks :)

Comment: @savagius: From your description, the JSON is getting deserialized properly. However, the default `toString()` implementation for an object returns a string in the format you described: the object's class and memory location. Changing the `toString()` implementation allows you to see the actual data contained in each `RepChanges` object.

Comment: Hi again, guys, my apologies for not responding immediately, I attempted to test out the reply by @deporter... In theory your response should be valid (however, I think I'm missing some minor detail because of which none is being printed).  In spite of this, I debugged my method and it seems that the RepChange object (class) is being filled as it should be :D

Thank you for your time :)